# Android how to generate apk with playStopIvPlayer.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.circuler_progress) using animation file in gradle version 1.5.0?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-gradle-plugin, android-drawable

I want to use an animation file on my player icon. when my file will be loaded then i set an animation.
here is my code :-

```
 playStopIvPlayer.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.circuler_progress);
 animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) playStopIvPlayer.getBackground();
 animationDrawable.start();
```

It was worked on gradle version 1.3.0.

But when i update my gradle version 1.5.0, it also worked and running successfully. 
But i can't generate a signed APK. When i want to generate signed APK the error message was "Expected resource of type drawable"

How can i solve it?

I need some help. how can i generate signed APK.

Comment: setBackgroundResource expects a drawable resource

Comment: but that code was running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Move your circuler_progress xml file to res/drawable folder, and change your java class:

```
playStopIvPlayer.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.circuler_progress);
```

to

```
playStopIvPlayer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circuler_progress);
```

It worked for me for an Eclipse project migration to Android Studio 1.5